# fixing html errors

Tags: wysiwyg, html

I am creating my own custom theme with Magento for the first time. When I add a product, in the 'full description', I use the html editor instead of the wysiwyg editor as I copy and paste an html template to keep every product view consistent.

The problem I have is if I make an html error in the product description such leaving out a closing html tag etc, something in my theme messes up. To stop this, once I have added the description in the html editor, I click the button that switches to wysiwyg editor then click submit, that way, if I make any html error in the html editor, the wysiwyg editor will fix it.

However, if I forget to do this, somewhere in my theme messes up. Does anyone know how I can find out what product is causing this problem if it happens in the future?

for example, I add many products a week and regularly make theme tweaks as my website isn't live yet. I noticed recently my footer wasn't full width as it should be, when I inspect element for the footer I noticed something unusual in the html so I looked at some of my template files to see where the problem is, then I realised It is probably because I didn't press that wysiwyg button for one of my products in the product description. So I have to go to each product, pressing the wysiwyg button then press the submit until the problem is fixed.

So if this happens again, is there anyway to find out what product is causing the problem so I don't have to go to each product.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use validators, such as this one:

http://validator.w3.org/

They give you pretty good indication what tags are left unopened and this helps you pinpoint the product with broken html. All in all your page should validate 100%; it's not just good for general hygiene, it's also good for SEO as Google prefers valid web pages because it usually means better content quality.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. That just might work if I run into that problem again. It also stated I had a couple of errors that I just fixed :)